# cbbackupmgr restore gets stuck when resident ratio becomes 0%

Tags: couchbase

I am observing that the **cbbackupmgr** utility is getting paused while doing a restore for a bucket. This is happening when the resident ratio becomes 0. How and why does the resident ratio becomes 0 here although I see there is data in the memory?

**Note:** The bucket data is about *3* GB and the bucket quota is set to *20%* of this, so around *600* MB. Bucket quota is set so that the resident ratio doesn't exceed *20%*.

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server are you using? On which operating system?